# How to get Id's from dynamic grid view in eclipse and appium, and how can I click the view in grid layout

Tags: eclipse, appium, appium-android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Jzfl.png)When I try to automate the mobile application, I'm not able to find the id/xpath/class of a particular view in dynamic grid view. I tried with UIautomatorviewer, but I'm not able to do.

1st try:

```
driver.findElementByXPath("android.widget.ImageView[@text ='text']").click();
```

2nd try:

```
List<MobileElement> mlist = driver.findElements(By.id("package:id/mid_5"));
mllist.get(0).click();
```

Expected output is to click the view in grid layout by using id/xpath/class. The views of grid layout are taken dynamically in android.

Comment: You're on the right track.  You should read any repeated (grid-like) elements into List, but keep in mind that the list will only contain items visible, so as you scroll you'll need to reload the list.  The problem is probably your locator.  Is your driver defined as AppiumDriver?  Xpath should start with "//" but that's not necessarily why it failed - I'd have to see a screenshot of the UIAutomator screen

Comment: I suggest you to use appium desktop inspector instead of uiautomatorviewer as it will suggest you automation id or id of the element if there are any. it will also show you the xpath to that element.